# Wrapping sheet music into a circle

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a piece of sheet music i want to wrap around a vinyl center art
whats the best way to do this in photoshop that maintains legibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a high resolution image, you can apply Photoshop's Filters > Distort > Polar coordinates to get this:

[image]

You start from one horizontal line to get one circular line. The original must be  placed in the middle of a square image. It must be rotated 180 degrees and stretched vertically to get wide enough circular score line to clockwise direction.

No stretching will produce distortionless result because the bending will treat lower and upper notes differently. You must experiment and undo, if needed. Start with 200% vertical scaling.

Before applying "polar coordinates" it was this 8200 px x 8200 px image:

[image]

Do not expect anything usable in screen resolution.

This method can be applied several times to get more lines. If you need a spiral, you can make an image pattern brush. Illustrator CC and Affinity Designer know it.

If you can retype the score in a music notation program, you very likely can output a vector PDF, which can be splitted and used as a vector pattern brush in Illustrator.

If you can read the example, you see that one circle presents only about 17 seconds of single tone music in medium tempo.

Comment: That's assuming it's one line of music. "Sheet music" is generally a whole sheet filled with several lines of music.

Comment: thank you this is perfect, by how much did you vertically stretch you sheet music?

Comment: @Billy Kerr here's 3 single stave lines due the value of Pi; it's about 3. I guess one could make two rings more  and keep it still readable. But inner rings cannot contain as much except if they were scaled.

Comment: @thomaswilbrink I augmented the answer to say something about the stretching.

Answer (score 3):

My gut reaction to this is that given the necessary rescaling on the outer side of the curve in any circular alignment, you don't want to do this in Photoshop, or any raster editor - I think this will only work well in a vector art arena - Illustrator, Inkscape, Affinity Designer.

Comment: i've tried that but there's no vector library for the notes or other parts of music so i can not import my sheet music into vector

Comment: @thomaswilbrink if you try to stretch a raster image round a circle like that it will cause severe distortion and blurring. That's why GerardFalla is suggesting vector software. It's really the only way to do it without degradation in quality. Raster image editors are really no good for this kind of work.